# How do I remove all elements that occur more than once in a list?

Tags: python-3.x, list, recursion, indexoutofrangeexception

Although there are several similar questions about this problem, they could not help me at all so I am asking you right now:

Let's say I have a list like this:

```
list = [3, 8, 4, 8, 3, 9, 8]
```

After checking, I want to have an output like that:

```
list = [4, 9]
```

I have tried the following, but its output for the list above are two lists that contain every number once (I guess similar to a set) and after a certain time there is finally a list index out of range error:

```
def listchecker(list):
    for i in range(0, len(list)):
        for j in range(i + 1, len(list)):
            if list[i] == list[j]:
                del list[i]
                listchecker(list)
    print("Updated list:", list)
```

I totally understand that this is not the right way -  I probably rather need something to safe the index for the element that occurs more than once and delete its value by iterating over the list again ...but I don't know how to proceed on that.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not sure why you need recursion here. As the duplicate shows, build a dictionary with counts, then only keep items with a count of 1.

Comment: Yeah cool, Thanks! I think I need to figure out how this exactly works, but it definitely seems to be sufficient:)